# FCM - Stops receiving notification if app is closed for some time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This simple example works strangely. If my test app is running (on foreground), all push are received fine. If I close my app, after some time, push is no longer received.

I send all push from Firebase console with a `high` priority. Tried it on Android 5 and 6.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}
}

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm">


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
    <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->
</application>
```

Comment: How are you closing your app? Backgrounding it with the Home button? Swiping it away in the Recents list? Force stop?

Comment: Finish my activity by press on Back button.

Comment: did you resolved, i am facing same problem , help me

Comment: Not resolved :(